# Link to Task on Large List

Tags: 2013, list

I have a list of 130 tasks.  I want to create a link directly to a task without user having to scroll through entire task list from beginning.  I do not want it to open in edit.

Comment: Can you give a link to the display form rather than the edit form?

Comment: I want the link to direct to the specific task on the list, not open the task.  Just default link to the line item.  ID=? opens the task and I do not want that. Just highlight to the task.  User can then open it if they choose.

Answer (score 0):

Your user interaction would be:

- Open page
- What is the Item I want to scroll to?
- scroll down to item

So that is what you have to replicate in (javascript) code on your List View page

- Get the ID from from the URL
- get the TR-Table Row with the matching ID
- scroll page up until that TR is in the viewport

Comment: It may be slightly more complicated than that taking into account item limit / paging.

Comment: I do not understand your answer.  Answer is not useful

Comment: As you do not understand the answer, I conclude you can't do the javascripting part. I am sorry to say there is no OOB solution